# Can a custom beamer theme be recovered from auxiliary files?

Tags: beamer, auxiliary-files, themes, beamerposter

A custom beamertheme file used to specify many of the formatting details of a beamerposter document has been deleted/removed from my system.

The large majority of files (`.tex`, `.pdf`, `.aux`, `.txt`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, `.out`, `.run`, `.snm`, `.syntex.gz`, `.nav`, `.toc`) associated with the beamerposter document remain on the system still.

On question is, with the aux files, can the beamertheme document be reconstituted?  Would there be any other way to get the key details out of the custom beamertheme document?

My guess is no but thought that I would ask to confirm.  I searched most of the files of material size only to find a reference to the external, custom beamertheme file I was using in the log file.

Note that the path was my local texmf tree:

`C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\themes\beamertheme<name>.sty`

Comment: I don't think there is much hope to recover anything. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid, you will not find much in the auxillary files that would help you to reconstruct your theme.

Most of the changes done by traditional beamer themes (colours, fonts etc.) is done when the content is typeset.